# VBA Excel ERROR 1004 problems with Paste Value

Tags: vba, excel

I am kind of new with `VBA` and I have a problem I cannot solve and cannot find the right solutions in earlier questions. In fact it looks quite simple. I want to copy a range in worksheet with the name `"Blad3"` and paste the values in in worksheet with the name `"Blad1"`. This is what I made and where does it go wrong?

```
    ActiveSheet.Cells(dattel, 4).Select

    ActiveCell.Range("A1:J1").Copy

    Sheets("Blad1").Select
    Cells(8 + aantkk, 6).Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
'    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Comment: Yes, please answer on what line it does go wrong and what error message you get

Comment: It would not be a surprise to learn that `Unprotect` ends the `CutCopyMode` so a paste would not work. The [real answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) to your question though is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787935/11683). Having that done, you should really see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the real answer to your dilemma is to [protect the worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel) with the **UserInterfaceOnly:=True** parameter so that you do not have to Unprotect it to write values using VBA code.

Run this once.

```
sub protectBlad1FromUser()
    worksheets("Blad1").unprotect
    worksheets("Blad1").protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end sub
```

Now you can do anything you want to the Blad1 worksheet in VBA while protecting it from the user.

As to your original code, it is confusing. If `.Cells(dattel, 4)` is D4 on the Blad3 worksheet then `ActiveCell.Range("A1:J1").Copy` doesn't copy A1:J1; it copies D4:M4. In any event, direct value transfer is a more efficient method of transferring values than Copy, Paste Special, Values.

```
dim rng as range
set rng = worksheets("blad3").cells(dattel, 4).resize(1, 10)  '<~~ figure out what this is supposed to be
with worksheets("Blad1")
    .cells(8 + aantkk, 6).resize(rng.rows.count, rng.columns.count) = rng.value
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now ERROR 438 when I type this code

Comment: My apologies; I should have compiled that before posting. I only wrote it off the top of my head; turns out I wrote off the bottom of a lower anatomy area. Change `rng.values` to `rng.value` as fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

Sheets("Blad3").Range("A1:J1").Copy

Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:J1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue

I tested it on a new workbook and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

May be try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad3")   'this is source sheet
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")  'this is destination sheet

    With destSht
        .Unprotect                           'unprotect sheet Blad1
        Set rng = srcSht.Range("A1:J1")      'set range to copy
        .Cells(8 + aantkk, 6).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 'paste only values
        .Protect                             'protect sheet Blad1
    End With
End Sub
```

`SELECT` and `ACTIVATE` should be avoided. See [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/27/beginning-vba-select-and-activate/) for details.